# Rendimiento de mi pagina web

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas comunidad,

De esta forma hago uso de las sesiones en el archivo principal para diferenciar las interfaces de un usuario común a un administrador por ejemplo:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
  {
    if ($_SESSION['usuario']['desc_tipo_usuario'] != "adminEmpresa")
    {
      header('Location: adminEmpresa.php');
    }
  }
  else {
    header('Location: index.php');
  }
?>
```

Pero acctualmente cuento con más de 15 archivos PHP dentro de los cuales declaro el uso de SESIONES:

```
session_start();
  $nit_empresa = $_SESSION['usuario']['nit'];
  $id_empresa  = $_SESSION['usuario']['id_empresa'];
```

He comprobado cada uno de los querys y todos respoden con una velocidad prudente para la carga de datos(Ej de uso de variable):

```
SELECT
pemp.nombre_punto,
cdes.ciudad,
cdes.id_departamento,
dpto.departamento,
pemp.descripcion_punto,
tusr.id_tipoDeUsuario,
tusr.desc_tipo_usuario,
empr.id_empresa,
empr.nit,
empr.ruta_logo,
prna.usuario,
prna.password

FROM puntoempresa pemp
INNER JOIN ciudades cdes
ON cdes.id_ciudad = pemp.id_ciudades_punto    
INNER JOIN departamento dpto
ON dpto.id_departamento = cdes.id_departamento        
INNER JOIN persona prna
ON prna.id_usuario_punto = pemp.id_puntoEmpresa
INNER JOIN tipodeusuario tusr
ON tusr.id_tipoDeUsuario = prna.id_tipoUsuario
INNER JOIN empresa empr
ON empr.id_empresa = prna.empresa_per
WHERE empr.nit = '$nit_empresa'
AND empr.id_empresa = '$id_empresa'
```

Posteriormente en mis consultas las uso como variables para tener una consulta mucho mas estructurada de los datos, pero mi duda surge en cuanto a qué el uso de las sesiones en todos mis archivos CRUD, esté alterando la velocidad de carga de todo el proyecto como tal.

Dado que al momento de usar "F5" o usar el botón de actualizar el navegador se toma un promedio de carga de 15 segundos, lo que molesta a la mayoría de usuarios que hacen uso del sistema.

Buscando un poco me he encontrado con este tipo de problematica, ¿Cómo podría optimizar el uso de sesiones?:

> **Sesiones de usuario pesadas:** Cada usuario que accede al sitio o aplicación web requiere de una capacidad de memoria para que el servidor procese sus peticiones y entregue el contenido. Si esta necesidad de recursos es muy elevada, la lentitud del servicio se va hacer notoria exponencialmente cada vez que accedan más usuarios. En este caso deberías revisar y optimizar el código para hacer más ligera cada sesión o bien aumentar los recursos disponibles correctamente

Comment: yo de ti usaría cookies encriptas pues así tengo una página, y al hacer eso lo que hace es almacenar los datos de parte del usuario y que el servidor solo se encargue de hacer una petición para atraer los datos de un query para mostrar los datos del usuario junto con todos los privilegios del mismo sin adsorver capacidad del servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi me pasaba algo parecido con el rendimiento y encontre que en realidad estaba llamando muchas veces a la base de datos por datos que no cambiaban seguido, digamos los persmios de usuarios por ej.
entonces empece almacenar mas variables de sesión con mas datos estáticos y el sistema termino funcionando de maravilla, otra cosa es que empece a usar indices en las consultas a la base de datos, pase de leer 5000 registros de reclamos y maso menos 4 observaciones cada reclamo en 15s a leer 13000 registros en ese tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza ajax para no volver a cargar tu pagina y solo actualizar la información en tu pagina que el usuario necesita.
puedes ver Tutoriales de como usarlo como por ejemplo el de JQUERY de codigo facilito. y asi evitas volver a cargar el session o bien usar las cookies

Comment: Seria viable, pero me tocaria volver a reestructurar todo el proyecto en AJAX y no en Angular como actualmente esta desarrollado.